# ArcMap label expressions with Python

Tags: python, arcmap, labeling

Having trouble here: I'm trying to use python to write selective label expressions. I have several concentrations and depending on its "_Ex" number I either want it labeled red, not red, or not labeled at all. I have started with just one trying to set it to red. when i put this into the lable expression it says line one Findlabel not defined.

Any help would be appreciated. -Acrain  (Indentations are not showing up correctly here, but I don't think thats my problem)

```
def FindLabel ([cis12DCE] , [cis12DCE_Ex]):

if short ( [cis12DCE_Ex] ) = 1:
    return "<clr red = "255">"+"cis-1,2-Dichloroethylene  "+[cis12DCE]+"</clr>
else:   
    return "cis-1,2-Dichloroethylene  "+[cis12DCE]
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my answer.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple issues.

1. You seem to be having a problem with indentations and extra spacing between your def line and your `if` statement.  The `if` statement needs to be on the next line.
2. I think you are embedding a series of double quotes inside each other.

Edit - Change expression to double `==` sign, HT @Hotpepper

Edit 2 - I am including a screenshot of how the expression should be entered in the expression window.  In addition, based on the error, I think you should simply try casting the field back to an integer `int` instead of using `short`, as I'm not sure that is supported.

For reference, here is the relevant ESRI Help document:  [Building Label Expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000)

Try:

```
def FindLabel ([cis12DCE],[cis12DCE_Ex]):
  if int([cis12DCE_Ex]) == 1:
    return "<clr red = '255'>"+"cis-1,2-Dichloroethylene  "+[cis12DCE]+"</clr>"
  else:   
    return "cis-1,2-Dichloroethylene  "+[cis12DCE]
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help, I made your changes but am still getting an error. Is there a specific way to enter/copy the code into the parser?

Comment: I have added the error to my main question

Comment: Fantastic thank you soooo much. Works perfectly I can build off this. Thanks again you really helped me out. -Adam

Comment: Glad that I could help.  I would appreciate it if you would mark this answer as accepted.  This will help other people who are searching for something similar.

Comment: @ACrain - Just wondering why you switched the accepted label to the other answer.  I could understand if that was the only issue with the expression, but I thought there were a number of factors I helped you out with.  Glad to help regardless, and hope you get your problem solved.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, it has been switched back

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing an equals sign in your if statement 
if short ( [cis12DCE_Ex] ) = 1: 
should be
if short ( [cis12DCE_Ex] ) == 1:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def FindLabel ([cis12DCE],[cis12DCE_Ex]):
  if int([cis12DCE_Ex]) == 1:
    return "<clr red = '255'>"+"cis-1,2-Dichloroethylene  "+str([cis12DCE])+"</clr>"
  else:   
    return "cis-1,2-Dichloroethylene  "+str([cis12DCE])
```